# How to make a JFrame scrollable?

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jframe

I would like to scroll through the contents of my `JFrame` up and down, preferably with a scroll bar. I don't want to wrap the contents inside a `JPanel` or `JScrollPane`, because this causes some visual glitches with my application.

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: What kind of visual glitches? It might be easier to fix them than invent a new scrolling system.

Comment: If wrapping your view in a JScrollPane or JPanel is causing visual glitches, then you are doing something wrong. Rather then trying to find a hack around it, you should focus on fixing the existing issues

Comment: You cannot apply a scrollbar directly to a JFrame. You need to use a JPanel or JScrollPane. Instead of avoiding those options, you should find out why they don't work right and fix it.

Comment: @MadProgrammer beat me to the punch

Comment: I'm creating a list which contains shows I'm watching online. I'm dynamically adding custom JPanels which contain the name, episode, etc. The JPanel also includes buttons that remove/update the JPanels. As soon as I update them this happens: http://imgur.com/a/iFSvs
Everything except the text disappears and I have to hover over each button with my cursor to make it visible again. This only happens if the custom panels are wrapped inside another JPanel/JScrollPane and not if I'm displaying them directly on the JFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JScrollPane would be the easiest way; you say there are glitches, but that probably indicates a problem in your code that will still be a problem even without using a JScrollPane.

If you're absolutely set on not using a JScrollPane, you should create a JPanel using BorderLayout, add a JPanel (call it 'center') with BorderLayout.CENTER and layout set to null. Add your content within 'center', and add another  JScrollBar to BorderLayout.EAST, add an AdjustmentListener to the JScrollBar. When the adjustmentListener triggers, you need to move your content (Component.setLocation(...)) that's in center to the relative y offset of the JScrollBar and call repaint on 'center'

Comment: I didn't think about moving the contents manually across the JFrame. Thank you.
Although I just hooked the controls to 2 buttons and move each individual element with setBounds(0, y, 650, 70) across the null layout JFrame since I have them all inside an ArrayList.